# How to Simplify Writing a Book of Poetry

Tags: formatting, poetry

I will write a **Book of Poetry**, written by many authors. I hope that each author will write a poem in a plain text file.

So far, I wrote a master file **BookOfPoetry.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{Poetry/FirstPoetry.txt}
\end{document}
```

and **FirstPoetry.txt**

```
\title{theTitle}
\author{theAuthor}
\date{theDate}
\maketitle
\begin{verbatim}
it is first line
it is second line
\end{verbatim}
```

How to simplify the writing of a text file with minimal formatting like this **FirstPoetryRev.txt**

```
theTitle
theAuthor
theDate

it is first line
it is second line
```

then the **BookOfPoetry.tex** will translate

- the `first line` as `the title`
- the `second line` as `the author`
- the `third line` as `the date`
- and (`space`)
- the `fifth line and so on` as `the content of the poem`, without writing `\\` at the end of each line.

Comment: Consider using the package 'fancyvrb' so you can control the font. Then have each author put each poem in a separate file with it formated by the author exactly as they want it to appear.

Comment: the authors aren't familiar with using `LaTeX`.

Comment: They don't need to be. That's why you pipe it in verbatim. I would just preprocess the files with `awk`, say, to add the `\title{}` `\author{}` `\date{}` `\maketitle` and whichever environment you end up using. You can do it with LaTeX. But I don't see the point.

Comment: Do you require any formatting of the content? Specifically, the title-related stuff?

Comment: I've downloaded GAWK from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), and then install it. I've tried to execute the program [makeitemizelist](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~sherwood/awk/makeitemizelist.awk.txt) and it work.

    `gawk -f makeitemizelist.awk FirstPoetry.txt`

But, the execution results displayed in the command window. How to make it as a LaTeX file?

Comment: @Werner, contributors wanted to write in a simple text file, then I would easily edit it using `LaTeX`.

Comment: @cfr, I've added the command `> file.tex` to write into LaTeX file.

Comment: the solution is as @R.Schumacher said with fancyvrb but there is a second problem since article class allow the use of \maketitle infos only once so you should define your propre style of formating of the master file.

Comment: I think a verbatim environnement is not very useful, because its... verbatim. In my sense the simpler solution will be to add a script which insert a \\ (if you use verse environnement) or a & (if you use stanza tools of eledmac) at the end of each line.

Comment: @Maïeul Yes, I tend to agree. I'd just pre-process it with `awk` and/or `sed` as I think it is the easiest way. The results will certainly be nicer with `verse`. However, if authors wish to specify particular indentations etc. as part of their poetry (as is sometimes the case), then a verbatim environment might still be the best option in terms of a balance between results and messing around!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
\ifcase\value{FancyVerbLine}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\huge#1\strut}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\LARGE#1\strut}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\Large#1}\else#1\fi}
\VerbatimInput{file}
\end{document}
```

**Edit table of contents add**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
\ifcase\value{FancyVerbLine}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\xdef\mttitle{#1}\huge#1\strut}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\mttitle\ by #1}\LARGE#1\strut}\or
\makebox[\textwidth]{\Large#1}\else#1\fi}
\VerbatimInput{file}
\newpage
\VerbatimInput{file1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A simple and elegant solution!

Comment: @touhami, How to add the title and author of each poem to the Table of Contents (TOC)?

Comment: In my case, it is necessary to add file extension.
`\VerbatimInput{FirstPoetry.txt}`
`\newpage`
`\VerbatimInput{SecondPoetry.txt}` etc.

Comment: @EdyJo I edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I will add my solution here.

I use memoir as the class and verse and gmverse packages. Gmverse is great and gives you:

1. automatic visual centering of each poem. (no need to enter the longest line and calc its length)
2. No need for \ at the end of each line (but NOT last line) if each stanza. This makes copy and paste from emails or text, word etc files much easier.

Then I use subfiles package which acts like *include* but each *subfile* also knows the name of the major doc file and can read the preamble (before \begin{document}) and therefore be compiled independently.
This makes editing, assembling and creating several collections (ie journal submissions) simpler than one big file. It also keeps the single poem template quite small. Reordering is also easier.

So I re-use a template for each poem (on the Mac you set the file to be stationery in the info panel, and then a double click will give a new copy of the file) and rename them as needed.

Template for a single poem:

```
\documentclass[older_poems_40.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\vocweigh3      %needed for gmverse package, must be here not    
                %  in preamble

\thispagestyle{empty} %remove before using as subfile

\PoemTitle{TITLE} %%%% this will be numbered * version is not numbered
%\epigraph{}{}
\begin{verse} 
\index{FIRST_LINE}FIRST_line of poem
line 2
line 3

new stanza 1
line 2
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```

The main file of course has lots of formatting stuff in so I will add a truncated version here. (But note I have kept the list of poems (contents) and also the index of first lines (which needs you to re-run make index after you add a new subfile) for your pleasure.

```
%file = older_poems_40.tex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{memoir}


%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % I use Xetex so I don't need this anymore

\usepackage{epigraph}
    % set a note, subtitle quote or source under the poem title 
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.45\textwidth} % Was 0.4 
 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{verse, gmverse}
\usepackage{currfile} %% to get a compile date for records/sanity
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\PoemTitlefont}{\Large\slshape\centering} 


\title{Your poetry book name here}

\author{Your name here!}
\date{}


\hypersetup{
pdftitle={poems of blah},
pdfsubject={blah},
pdfauthor={David J. Garbutt},
pdfkeywords={poetry}
}
% or set to blank for anonymous submissions 


\usepackage{subfiles}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.  DOCUMENT%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\epigraph{street }{town, postcode, country}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\vfill

Compiled from \texttt{\currfilepath} on \today{}.

\clearpage

\subfile{poem1}

\clearpage
\subfile{poem2} %.tex is assumed

%% repeat lots of poems…
%% here I have clear pages only in the master file this makes it easier
%% to create a more compact version if wanted. 

%%%%% end poems
\renewcommand\indexname{Index of First Lines}
\onecolindex

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

It is up to you to make sure the file pointed to in the single poem template is the one with the  subfile statements in!